# How to obtain my QTP script resuts in xml file format (not that one present in the result folder)?

Tags: xml, qtp

I am running scripts in batches in QTP. I am able to get the results in excel file. Below is the function for getting the results in excel file format. How can I modify to get the results as xml file format?

```
Function WriteTestSet(TestSetPath, sheetname, varr )
set wb = xl.workbooks.open(TestSetPath)
set ws = wb.worksheets(sheetname)

rc = ubound(varr, 1) + 1
cc = ubound(varr, 2) + 1

for i = 1 to rc
    for j = 1 to cc
        ws.cells(i, j) = varr(i-1, j-1)
    next
next

wb.saveas "E:\TestResults\TestSet" & ".xlsx" 
wb.close
```

End Function

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Did you found some manual assessing this issue or similar?

Comment: I want to obtain the results by using vb script[NOT manually]

Comment: And what did you tried yourself in vb script? What research have you done (If there is any program, app, script...)?

Comment: The most obvious way would be to take the xml result, and apply an xsl transformation to it so you receive exactly the XML structure you want. (The result XML schema is well-defined and -documented.)